# How to find the radius of the smallest circle such that the inner ellipse is tangent to the circle at exactly one point?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

Consider the ellipse
$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1,$ where $a > b > 0.$ As a function of $a$ and $b,$ find the radius of the smallest circle that contains the ellipse, is centered on the $y$-axis, and which intersects the ellipse only at $(0,b).$

[image]

I have no clue how to solve this. The only thing I've thought of is that maybe it somehow involves the fact that for any $x$, the corresponding $y$ value of the circle is bigger than the corresponding $y$ value of the ellipse. But I haven't made much progress with that.

Comment: Look up "Gaussian curvature" which is the method of finding the radius of curvature at a point.

Comment: Make the second derivative of the circle equal to the second derivative of the ellipse at $(0,b)$

Comment: Or, for a calculus-free solution, concentrate all four intersections ot these two conics at $(0,b)$ by finding the quadratic equation in $y$ alone whose roots are the $y$-coordinates of the intersections. Adjust $r$ now so that this equation has one double root. It may well be that the strategy of @WW1 is quicker.

Comment: @Lubin - have you tried doing it that way?

Comment: Yes, @SuzuHirose , and I checked my formula for the final answer with an example. I must say that your method was about five times quicker.

Comment: @Lubin I did it that way too at first.

Answer (score 4):

Parameterise the ellipse as $x=a\cos t$, $y=b\sin t$.
This gives $x'=-a\sin t$, $x''=-a\cos t$, and $y'=b\cos t$, $y''=-b\sin t$.

Using [this formula from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization), the curvature is then
$$
\begin{align}
\kappa &= \frac{x'y''-y'x''}{\left({x'}^2+{y'}^2\right)^{3/2}}\\
&=
{
ab
\over
(a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2t)^{3/2}
}
\end{align}
$$
and at the top of the ellipse we have $t=\pi/2$ so this becomes $ab/a^3=b/a^2$. The radius of curvature is $1/\kappa=a^2/b$, so the circle has radius $a^2/b$.

Comment: No, there are not "infinitely many circles" for which the radius of curvature is the same "as in the above figure". This circle is uniquely specified. But if there were, they would all be the same size, since they would all have the same radius.

Comment: FWIW, I have a brief derivation of the curvature formula here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4023152/207316 which may be less confusing than that Wikipedia article.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you. Almost anything is less confusing than Wikipedia mathematics articles, what is up with those Wikpedians? It seems like they are deliberately obfuscating the mathematics. Unfortunately other sites come and go, so linking to Wikipedia is the only real option for links which stick around.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Wikipedia is written by "the people", so if you see room for improvement, *make improvements!* :)

Comment: Yes that sounds like a fun idea.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Thanks for you reply to my wrong comment.

Answer (score 1):

First solution, without calculus.

Let the circle have its centre at $(0,-k)$ and touch the ellipse at $(0,b)$, so that its equation is
$$
x^2+(y+k)^2=(b+k)^2.
$$
Substitute here $x^2=a^2-{a^2\over b^2}y^2$ from the ellipse equation and expand to get:
$$
{a^2-b^2\over b^2}y^2-2ky+b^2-a^2+2bk=0.
$$
This always has $y=b$ as a solution, while the other solution is:
$$
y={b^3-a^2b+2b^2k\over a^2-b^2}.
$$

For $k>0$ small enough this will give the ordinate of two other intersection points, but increasing the value of $k$ we eventually get $y>b$, which must be discarded because it entails $x^2<0$. In that case there are no other intersections between circle and ellipse and the ellipse entirely lies inside the circle. The limiting value of $k$ is then obtained for $y=b$: plugging that into the above equation and solving for $k$ we thus find the limiting value
$$
k={a^2-b^2\over b}
$$
and the radius of the smallest circle containing the whole ellipse:
$$
r=b+k={a^2\over b}.
$$

---

Second solution, purely geometric.

> The radius of curvature at a point $P$ of an ellipse is the harmonic
> mean of the diameters of the circles tangent to the ellipse at $P$ and
> passing through either focus of the ellipse

[See here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3457101/255730).

In our case the foci are at the same distance $a$ from $P=(0,b)$ and the circles described above are coincident. Their diameter $PQ$ is the hypothenuse of a right triangle (see figure) and by similar triangles we then have $PQ:a=a:b$, whence $PQ=a^2/b$. This is then the requested radius of curvature.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a rundown of this answer including diagrams, please check out this [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qm2aryvilp) graph.

Let us change the framing of this question. Consider instead a circle centred at the origin at radius $r$. Then if we translate the ellipse $r$ units upwards, its centre will be at $(0, r)$, with the vertical semi-major axis having length $b$. It thus follows that we can parametrise the ellipse in these new coordinates as:

$$(x(t), y(t)) = (a \cos t, b \sin t + r - b) \tag{$0 ≤ t < 2 \pi$}$$

Consider the squared distance function to the origin $r(t) = (a \cos t)^2 + (b \sin t + r - b)^2$. We know that $r(\pi/2)$ must equal $r^2$ exactly so that the $x$-coordinate is $0$ for the tangent point, after discounting $t = 3 \pi/2$: this will be our sanity check. We also know that this distance must be locally constant in the neigbourhood of $t = \pi/2$, so moreover, $f'(\pi/2) = 0$ (a local maximum in fact). Looking at the diagram, with $t$ going anticlockwise around the ellipse, $r(t)$ is increasing at first, then stabilises at $t = \pi/2$ before it decreases, which makes sense.

However, the information that $f'(\pi/2) = 0$ is not sufficient to express $r$ in terms of $a, b$. Without finding $f'(t)$ explicitly, we note that there will be a factor of $\cos t$ in both $(a \cos t)^2$, and $\cos t$ will appear too in the second term due to the chain rule $(\sin t)' = \cos t$. However, $\cos(\pi/2) = 0$ so we end up with $0 = 0$, a tautology.

The natural step would be then to observe $f''(t)$ around $t = \pi/2$. And the second derivative *is* enough information for the ellipse to have the same radius of curvature as its tangent circle.

Because a circle's distance to the origin is constant. Not only is its first derivative $0$, but its second derivative must equal $0$, and so must its third derivative. *And any function wishing to approximate a circle around a point with a given radius of curvature must satisfy at least the first and second conditions* (the higher derivatives do specify additional information which the radius of curvature cannot capture alone).

Now let us see if using the second derivative: $r''(\pi/2) = 0$ yields any new information. And it does indeed:

$$r'(t) = a^2 (2 \cos t)(-\sin t) + 2(b \sin t + r - b)(b \cos t)$$
$$= -a^2 \sin 2t + b^2 \sin 2t + 2b(r-b)\cos t$$

$$r''(t) = -2a^2 \cos 2t + 2b^2 \cos 2t+ 2b(b - r) \sin t$$

hence $r''(\pi/2) = 0$ yields $-2a^2 \cdot -1 + 2b^2 \cdot -1 + 2b(b-r) = 0$, or:

$$2a^2 - 2b^2 + 2b^2 - 2br = 0 \implies 2br = 2a^2 \implies \boxed{r = \frac{a^2}{b}}.$$

Comment: There's a lot more visual intuition in the Desmos graph that did not need to be included in this solution. For instance, how is $r(t)$ locally a concave down quartic, and not say a quadratic? What happens to $r'(t)$ as you play with the slider controlling $t$? Even more of  an extension, what pattern is there in the even- and odd-powered derivatives?

Comment: I actually played around with the derivatives and I noticed that all of those higher derivatives being 0 would not hold unless $a = b$: a perfect circle. It seems really obvious to say, but a point, a tangent line at that point, and a radius of curvature determines exactly two circles in opposite directions (you need to see it interactively to be able to get some sort of insight as to why). Thus there is no 'other information' that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without calculus.

Eliminating $x$ in the set $\cases{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\\ x^2+(y-y_0)^2= r^2}$ we obtain

$$
\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)y^2-2y_0y+y_0^2-r^2=0
$$

now solving for $y$ to determine the intersections we have

$$
y = \frac{-y_0\pm\sqrt{y_0^2-(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)(r^2-y_0^2-a^2)}}{(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)}
$$

but we need tangency so this implies on an unique solution so the condition is

$$
y_0^2-(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)(r^2-y_0^2-a^2)=0
$$

solving for $r$ we get

$$
r = \frac{\sqrt{a^4-a^2b^2+a^2y_0^2}}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
$$

but $r=b-y_0$ and thus we obtain $y_0 = \frac{b^2-a^2}{b}$ and $r = \frac{a^2}{b}$

Comment: Tangency is not tied to a single solution for $y$, see my answer.

Comment: And then: how do you get your expression for $y_0$? Doesn't seem to come from the solution for $r$.

Comment: First $y_0$ and then $r$.

Comment: Why did you solve for $r$ then?

Comment: Because my purpose was to solve the question as a tangency problem.

Comment: Mmm, but how did you get $y_0={b^2-a^2\over b}$?

Comment: Using the well known Bhaskaracharya formula.

Comment: I used it too but didn't get that result.

Comment: Simplifying $\frac{a^4-a^2b^2+a^2y_0^2}{a^2-b^2}-(b-y_0)^2=0$ we arrive at $1+\frac{by_0}{a^2-b^2}=0$

Comment: I spotted the error: the correct solution is $$r=\frac{\sqrt{a^4-a^2 b^2-a^2 y_0^2+2 b^2 y_0^2}}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}.$$

Comment: The error comes from a changed plus sign. The expression $y_0^2-(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)(r^2+y_0^2-a^2)=0$ should be $y_0^2-(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)(r^2-y_0^2-a^2)=0$ as it is now. A flaw in formula transcription. Sorry for the additional work caused.

Comment: $x^2+(y-y_0)^2= r$ should be $x^2+(y-y_0)^2= r^2$ and $\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)y^2-2y_0y+y_0^2-r^2=0$ should be $\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)y^2-2y_0y+y_0^2-r^2+a^2=0.$ These are obviously transcription errors, since in each case the error is corrected in the next formula, but the latter equation caused me all kinds of grief trying to use your work before I checked it.

Comment: I think things are a little simpler if you substitute $y_0=b-r$ in $y_0^2-(\frac{a^2}{b^2}-1)(r^2-y_0^2-a^2)=0$ (or even earlier, for example in the original system of equations, to reduce the number of variables). This reduces quickly to $r^2 - 2\dfrac{a^2}{b}r  + \dfrac{a^4}{b^2} = 0$, that is, $(r - \dfrac{a^2}{b})^2 = 0$.